# Why is python console not picking up pyenv global version?

Tags: python, pyenv

```
ishandutta2007@MacBook-Pro:~$ python --version
```

> ```
> Python 2.7.15
> ```

```
 ishandutta2007@MacBook-Pro:~$ pyenv versions
```

> ```
>   system
>   2.7
> * 3.7.0 (set by /Users/ishandutta2007/.pyenv/version)
> ```

```
 ishandutta2007@MacBook-Pro:~$ pyenv global 3.7.0
 ishandutta2007@MacBook-Pro:~$ pyenv versions
```

> ```
>   system
>   2.7
> * 3.7.0 (set by /Users/ishandutta2007/.pyenv/version)
> ```

```
ishandutta2007@MacBook-Pro:~$ python --version
```

> ```
> Python 2.7.15
> ```

```
ishandutta2007@MacBook-Pro:~$ python
```

> ```
> Python 2.7.15 (default, Jun 17 2018, 12:46:58) 
> [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.2)] on darwin
> Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
> ```

Comment: Can you run and post the output of `pyenv version` before and after `pyenv global`?

Comment: updated as per your request

Comment: `python3 --version` will work. Python (version 2.x) and Python 3 (version 3.x) are two different pieces of software

Comment: do you have eval "$(pyenv init -)" in your .bash_profile or .bashrc , could you do echo $PATH

Comment: Thanks @dilkash that was the problem, you can move it to answer

Comment: @ishandutta2007 added, do you mind marking it correct :)

Comment: @dilkash I was waiting for your reply, I thought you wouldn't so ended up posting it myself. Anyways maked yours as accepted as it was the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add:

```
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
```

in your .bash_profile or .bashrc

Answer (score 0):

The issue was I needed to add this in my `bash_profile`

```
if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then
  eval "$(pyenv init -)"
fi
```